Avoid unescaped user controlled content in EL error in salesforce PMD
I am facing this error Avoid unescaped user controlled content in EL on line  
cant find a solution to this can anyonehelp. have search multiple thread but this error is not going :(


this is where its happening
And this is what i did:

Your Link Text

